# How to delete DIV when click using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am populating multiple DIV with multiple IDs with PHP loop,

```
 foreach($usernotes_array as $usernote)
     {
        ?>
<div class="todo-tasklist-item todo-tasklist-item-border-red" id="usernotebox<?php echo $usernote['thread_id'];?>">
<p>somenote</p>
<a href="javascript:removeusernote();"><i class="fa fa-trash-o pull-right"></i></a>
</div>
        <?php
        }
     ?>
```

This loop is repeated with each tread_id,

Now i had added a delete button with JS function,
This function will do AJAX call to delete note from DB, and should delete DIV from HTML as well,

Below is my JS to delete note,

```
function removeusernote(){

        jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/phase/user/deleteusernote/"+<?php echo $userinfo->user_id; ?>,
                    data: {userthread_id:<?php echo $usernote['thread_id'];?>},
                    type: "POST",
                    success:function(data){ 
                                    var objData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

                                        if(objData.cival == 1)
                                                {

                                                  $("#usernotescounts").text(objData.usernotecounts);   

                                                      }
                                                      else
                                                      {
                                                        ....  
                                                      }
                                              }
                                    });
                    $( "#usernotebox<?php echo $usernote['thread_id'];?>" ).remove();
 }
```

Now my problem is that, how can i get ID of div in which i clicked for delete button?
Example, there are 3 divs with ID usernotebox1,2,3
Now when i click on usernotebox1, i should get that ID to delete and also thread_id number so i can pass that to DB for server side deletion,

I could able to achieve this by putting my JS in PHP loop, but i dont want to loop JS for each div,

Can someone help how to dynamically delete DIVs?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is simple logic, you just pass the unique id to anchor tag as well like:

```
<a href="javascript:removeusernote(<?php echo $usernote['thread_id'];?>);"><i class="fa fa-trash-o pull-right"></i></a>
```

and change your function to get:

```
    function  removeusernote(id){
 $( "#usernotebox"+id).remove();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```

Where $(this) will select your current element. .parent() will find the parent of current element that is your div. At last .remove() will remove your div.

Or you can also find your div by classname like this:

```
$(this).parents().find('.classname').remove();
```

Edits: Add this with the function like "removeusernote(this)"

```
foreach($usernotes_array as $usernote)
     {
        ?>
<div class="todo-tasklist-item todo-tasklist-item-border-red" id="usernotebox<?php echo $usernote['thread_id'];?>">
<p>somenote</p>
<a href="javascript:removeusernote(this);"><i class="fa fa-trash-o pull-right"></i></a>
</div>
        <?php
        }
     ?>
```

Do this in your function:

```
removeusernote(sender){
$(sender).parent().remove(); //this will remove your div
//after this you can continue with your code

}
```

Comment: thanks but how will i get ID for which i am doing delete as there are 3 divs with 3 delete button for each, it should send me ID for which i am deleting, means i need to have ID of div for find(div ID).

Comment: Check out the edits. you will find the generic solution for these types of problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
//This only works for div's with a class
$("[element]").on("click", function() {
  $(this).removeClass("[className]");
});
```